# Cannot access a disposed object?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, forms

I have a countdown Timer form - on the first form the user will enter the countdown time - warning times, end message, etc.  There are also two Radio buttons (Max/Min) and depending on which is selected they will open a new Max or Min form where the time will actually start to countdown.  It is working fine and counting down as I expect.  However, if I exit the Max or Min form and try to run again with new times I get the error.  The code is below - note the comment out ShowDialog(this); was something I tried - it let me close and open the new forms ok but it did not actually start the countdown.  UpdateLabels is the function that does the updating of Labels.

```
                bool Max = rbMax.Checked;
                if (Max == true)
                {
                    //_Max.ShowDialog(this);
                    _Max.Show();

                }
                else
                    //_Min.ShowDialog(this);
                    _Min.Show();

                UpdateLabels();
            }
```

I also tried the following which I read online as a possible solution but it also did not work...

```
    private void Max_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Hide();
        this.Parent = null;
    }
```

Can anyone help me out - I can post the UpdateLabels function if needed.  I am pretty new to UI C# development so any help would be great.  Thanks.

Comment: One notable difference between `Form.ShowDialog` and `Form.Show` is that the former does not automatically `Dispose` your form, while the latter does. The reason for this is that if you show a form mode-less (i.e. with `Form.Show`), program execution returns to your code *before* the form is closed, and you have no easy way of knowing when the form gets closed, outside your `Form` class. Therefore, because you have no good place from where to call `Dispose`, Windows Forms takes over the responsiblity of doing that for you at the proper time (when the form has closed).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is, that a closed form can not be used anymore (be reopened). Thats why the code you posted tries to stop closing and only hides your window. But for doing this, the Cancel-property must be set to true:

```
private void Max_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)    {        
   this.Hide();        
   this.Parent = null;    
   e.Cancel=true;
}
```

To show the form after closing it this way, show it with the Show() method.

However this is probably only a workaround and you could solve the problem with another design.
**Maybe it would be wise, to create a new instance of your form, every time you need it,** instead of trying to reopen it every time. This also has the advantage that the form only requesires resources if it is really needed.

Comment: I'll try that now - Ill let youu now how it goes. - Thanks HCL

Comment: That worked - great.  Many Thanks HCL.  Just for some understanding can you briefly explain what that was doing?  Cheers

Comment: @CollyMcK: I have extended my answer. Ok?

Comment: Thanks for the additional explanation and yes it may be better to do a bit more design but this workaround will be cool for now.

Comment: No, this way will prevent you close the form.

Answer (score 7):

What you can do is add a following check before calling .Show method:

```
if(_Max == null || _Max.IsDisposed)
    _Max = new MaxForm();       

_Max.Show();
```

and similarly for _Min form

Comment: THanks - this design - may be a better approach.

Comment: This won't be reliable. If multiple threads are accessing the form (or perhaps events) there is no guarantee that the form is still null after the if statement. At minimum, you would need to place a lock around every access of the form if you want this to work.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever a form is closed, **all its resources are freed**. This means that you can't access the object any more, since it no longer exists - it's been freed and deleted from memory. To prevent that, you can cancel the closing of the form, and hide it instead (which will appear transparent to the user).

```
this.Hide();        
e.Cancel=true;
```

An updated version of your code is as follows:

```
private void Max_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    e.Cancel = true;
    this.Hide();
    this.Parent = null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is simple that instantiate the object of the called form in the button click event e.g.

```
private void buttonSetting_Click( object sender, EventArgs e )
    {
        ***_setting = new SettingWindow();***  //When I need to show the settings window

        _setting.Show();
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! But please don't post solutions that have already been mentioned before. It's just noise to the question.

Answer (score 0):

create new instatnce if object is not available

if(frmRGB==nullptr  || frmRGB.IsDisposed==true )
                 {
                     frmRGB= new  Form();
                 }

Answer (score -1):

Create Object inside button click event
like this

```
private void btn_supplier_order_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            form_supplier_order so = new form_supplier_order();
            so.Show();
        }
```