# Cannot access a disposed object. Asynchronous print of messages in second form

Tags: c#, asynchronous

Asynchronous print of messages in second form.
System.ObjectDisposedException   in  System.Windows.Forms.dll during
close of second form.

MainForm runs SecondForm.
SecondForm runs message generator and asynchronous thread of print of messages in text box.
Message generator creates messages with random time delay.
Time delay in string format is this message.
Problem -
During close of second form, method SecondForm_Closing,
I receive exception

> System.ObjectDisposedException  in  System.Windows.Forms.dll
>   during Cannot access a disposed object.

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    secondForm SecondForm;
    private void MainForm_Closing(object o, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        Environment.Exit(0);
    }
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        SecondForm = new secondForm();
        SecondForm.Show();
    }
}
public partial class secondForm : Form
{
    private messageGenerator MessageGenerator;
    Action actPrint;
    //This method calls ObjectDisposedException then point to Invoke in method Print
    private void SecondForm_Closing(object o, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        Close();
    }
    public secondForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MessageGenerator = new messageGenerator();
        actPrint = new Action(Print);
        actPrint.BeginInvoke(null, null);
    }
    public void Print()
    {
        while (true)   //  Infinite  cycle
        {
            MessageGenerator.CreateEvent.WaitOne(); //  Wait event "Message is created"
            MessageGenerator.CreateEvent.Reset();//  Event reset
            Invoke(new MethodInvoker
            (() =>
            {
                TextBoxTimeDelay.Text = MessageGenerator.Message;//  Message print
            }));
        }
    }
}
public class messageGenerator
{
    public AutoResetEvent CreateEvent;
    public string Message;
    public Action actStart;
    public messageGenerator()
    {
        CreateEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);
        actStart = new Action(Start);
        actStart.BeginInvoke(null, null);
    }
    public void Start()
    {
        Random R = new Random();
        while (true)
        {
            int TimeDelay = 10 * R.Next(1, 5);
            Thread.Sleep(TimeDelay);
            Message = TimeDelay.ToString();
            CreateEvent.Set();  //  Event "Message is created"
        }
    }
}
```

Solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6993407/cannot-access-a-disposed-object?lq=1) not realizes of resources. 
I.e. MessageGenerator is continued, 
and Print method is worked. 
How to realizes the resources ?

```
private void SecondForm_Closing (object o, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    e.Cancel = true;
    this.Hide();
    this.Parent = null;
}
```

Comment: You really need to fix the formatting of that code; it's a mess.

Comment: Much MUCH MUUUUUUUUUCH BETTER

Comment: Yes, MessageGenerator imitates asynchronous date receive from internet.

Comment: Your question states you have an object disposed exception, but the comments in your code says you have a stack overflow exception.  Which is it?

Comment: I think you need to endInvoke actPrint in SecondForm_Closing. Since, you are using MessageGenerator object in Print Method which is disposed after form closing.

Comment: endInvoke was used - without result

Comment: Sorry! But after 
SecondForm_Closing (object o,FormClossingEventArgs)
{
 e.Cancel=true;
 Hide();
 Parent=null;
 Close();
}
Message Generator is continued.
I.e. SecondForm is not Closed.
What close this form?

Comment: Seems odd that you would call `Close` in the `SecondForm_Closing` event handler. Is this the actual code you're running? If so, what line, exactly, throws the exception?

Comment: Invoke (new MethodInvoker...
    in Print method

Comment: Why "odd" ?  Button "Cancel" click.

Comment: It is actual code, it is worked.