# Aborted thread can not be started a second time

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

I have a problem and don't know how to solve that. I'm starting a new thread:

```
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        Thread thrd = new Thread(new ThreadStart(loadingScreenStart));
        thrd.Start();

        //setting some variables, entering some methods etc...

        thrd.Abort();
}

public void loadingScreenStart()
{
        splashScreen splashObj = splashScreen.GetInstance();
        Application.Run(splashScreen.GetInstance());
}
```

In another form I have:

```
private static splashScreen m_instance = null;
private static object m_instanceLock = new object();

public static splashScreen GetInstance()
{
        lock (m_instanceLock)
        {
            if (m_instance == null)
            {
                m_instance = new splashScreen();
            }
        }
        return m_instance;
}
```

That works fine but when I hit the button a second time then I get an exception that there is no access to the discarded object. Why and how to solve that? I mean after the thread gets aborted I create a new one when hitting the button again.

Comment: I think you have issue with object not with the thread
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6993407/cannot-access-a-disposed-object

Comment: Why do you even abort the thread? It should usually be avoided to abort a thread. Just let the thread function finish executing and it'll die out. About your issue the splash screen is never set to null after the execution of it thus the handle is discarded and you return a discarded instance of it.

Comment: I need to abort it. Otherwise it won't close (It's showing a loading screen) and I get wrong values displayed

Comment: @Takeda15 - Aborting threads can leave your program in an undefined state. It should only ever be done when forcing a program to close.

Comment: @Enigmativity It's not *that* undefined. There's a lot of things that can't happen during `Thread.Abort`, the weird stuff only happens in your code (the bugs like "broken static constructors" have already been fixed in .NET). It's still a bad idea to use it here, of course.

Comment: The main problem here is that he's doing heavy work on the UI thread while trying to show a splash screen on a secondary UI thread. It would be a lot better if the heavy work was moved off to another thread instead.

Answer (score 0):

It's not the thread that is discarded, but the `splashScreen` instance. You should just create a new one, not try to reuse the old one.

Comment: I tried it now with "splashScreen splashObj = splashScreen.GetInstance();" before the Application.Run method but same error. I need to use some controls of the splashscreen form so the GetInstance method is the only way. Can't I destroy the object?

Comment: @Takeda15 Do you have any idea what your code does? It will *always* return the same `splashScreen` instance, no matter how many times you call `splashScreen.GetInstance()`. That's kind of the whole point of a singleton, but it obviously doesn't work when you *Dispose* of the singleton.

Answer (score 0):

```
Thread thrd = new Thread(new ThreadStart(loadingScreenStart));
thrd.Start();

//setting some variables, entering some methods etc...

thrd.Abort();
```

Why do you call thrd.Abort()? Did u know thread finish yet? 
You must wait thread finished.
And use double checking here

```
public static splashScreen GetInstance()
{
        if (m_instance == null)
        {
            lock (m_instanceLock)
            {
                if (m_instance == null)
                {
                   m_instance = new splashScreen();
                }
            }
        }
        return m_instance;
}
```

And maybe when you call Run splashscreen, it was disposed. Try create and capture it to a field and pass it to your method. Try this.

```
Task.Run(() => 
        var splashObj = splashScreen.GetInstance();
        Application.Run(splashObj);
    }));
```

Comment: Maybe you just var splashObj = new splashScreen(); Make sure your class is not disposed. Did you see the exception? Any exception? More detail.

Comment: No that doesn't works. He doesn't recognizes "var" and something is wrong with the brackets

Comment: Is it possible to detect if a thread is running in the background? Somehow I can't even access form1.thrd

Answer (score 0):

Ok I solved it somehow. Don't think that this is a good solution but it works. Instead of aborting the thread I just hide the Form of the SplashScreen and check if the thread is already running. If yes then I just Show the Form. If not I create a new instance.

Comment: Can't you just do `Form.Close()`?

Answer (score 0):

This is overly complicated and unsafe. If you really want to handle this using a "splash screen", why not try something like this?

```
using (var splashScreenForm = SplashScreen.ShowSplashScreen())
{
  // Do your work
}
```

Where `SplashScreen` has methods like this:

```
public static SplashScreen ShowSplashScreen()
{
  var form = new SplashScreen();

  new Thread(() => Application.Run(form)).Start();

  return form;
}

public override void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
  if (disposing)
  {
    if (InvokeRequired)
    {
      Invoke(() => base.Dispose(true));

      return;
    }

    base.Dispose(true);
  }
  else base.Dispose(disposing);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After taking another look at the whole thing I realized there's another problem here, and this is the entirely wrong direction to approach it from.

In your `button_Click` event you're obviously doing a lot of complicated stuff that takes a lot of time. Otherwise you wouldn't need to show a splash screen. However doing this in an event handler is a bad idea in itself. You totally lock up the UI thread and Windows will soon consider that window to be "hanged". It cannot even repaint itself!

So you should approach this from the completely opposite direction. Instead of trying to show the splash screen from another thread while using the UI thread for heavy work, just move the heavy work to the other thread! Then the splash screen won't need anything exotic like calling `Application.Start()` in another thread. Just a simple `.ShowModal()` will be enough. And when the other thread is done with its work, it can just call `.Close()` on your splash screen.

In a well designed application there is almost never a need for a second UI thread. It's the heavy work that needs to be moved to other threads, not UI.

Just be aware that if you want to manipulate the UI from another thread, you'll need to do some `Invoke()` stuff. Read more here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invokerequired(v=vs.110).aspx